# Matlab To Python conversion: SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matlab

This is my MATLAB code it runs fine.

```
% all of the given time are in milisecond
n = 3;     % No of image
T = 100;   % for the time period user wants to see the mirage

ts = .2*(100/(2*n-3));     % standing time
tv = .6*((100-((2*n-3)*ts))/(2*(n-1)));     % travelling time

m1 = 0:.1:tv;
x1 = .5*(1-cos(pi*(m1/tv)));      %position equation
xa = x1;

 
%travelling toward from left to right
for i= 1:n-1
    x1 = x1+i-1;
    %standing at one point
    for f = 1:ts
        x2(f) = x1(end);
    end
    if i==1
        x3=[x1,x2];
    else
        x3 = [x3,x1,x2];
    end
 
end
```

I'm trying to turn it into Python code. **It shows SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call**
This is Python code I came up with

```
import numpy as np
import math 
n = 3;                          
T = 100;                                          
ts = .2*(100/(2*n-3));                              
tv = .6*((100-((2*n-3)*ts))/(2*(n-1)));
m1 =   np.arange(0,tv,0.1); 
x1 = 0.5*(1-(np.cos(np.pi*(m1/tv)))); 
xa = x1;

##################################


#travelling toward from left to right
for i in range(1,n-1):
    x1 = x1+i-1;
    for f in np.arange(1,ts, ):     
        x2(f) = x1(end);            # The error line
        if i==1:
            x3 = np.array([x1,x2]);
        else:
            x3 = np.array([x3,x1,x2]);
```

How can I fix this? what changes can I make in the x2(f) = x1(end) because whatever I do it shows different error every time.

Comment: In python `f(x)` is a function call, `f[x]` is indexing.  `syntax error` means you've messed up some basic python thing.

Comment: When translating MATLAB to Python, I find it best to have two interactive sessions running - one MATLAB/Octave and other Python (ipython is my preferred).  Then execute each line, or block, and make sure values match.  You have confused () and [].  MATLAB lets you initial matrices with a simple `x2(f)`; In Python `x2` has to be created first, and be large enough.  You can't create or add values by simply indexing.  And the index has to be integer, not a float.  And the task is a lot easier if you have a basic command of both languages (my MATLAB knowledge is somewhat rusty).

Answer (score 0):

Indexing and slicing in python uses [] not ()

```
for i in range(1, n-1):
    x1 = x1 + i - 1;
    x2 = []
    for f in np.arange(1, ts):     
        x2.append(x1[-1])
        if i == 1:
            x3 = np.array([x1, x2])
        else:
            x3 = np.array([x3, x1, x2])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time but now another error is showing: NameError: name 'x2' is not defined

Comment: You should initialize x2 variable as empty array: x2 =[]

Comment: I updated the code with `x2 = []` and removed `;`. I also changed the assignment to `x2` to `append` which I think is a more pythonic way to do it

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend stop using semicolons. One of main python existence reasons is to make the code more readable.

Then, I would recommend not using blank arguments, it has no practical use if you do not do this intentionally:

```
for f in np.arange(1,ts):
```

About your program, you are doing something like function(some specific argument) assign function(argument under 'end' variable), if you want to operate with arrays you should use square brackets, curly are reserved for functions:

```
x2[f] = x1[end]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I followed your advice and initialized x2= [] but then another error shows up in the same line   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

Look at what the happens in Octave:

Initially `x2` is undefined, but is created when we start the `f` loop:

```
>> x2
error: 'x2' undefined near line 1 column 1
>> f=1
f =  1
>> x2(f) = x1(end)
x2 =  1
```

If I try to index it with the last value, `ts`, I get the same sort of error:

```
>> f=ts
f =  6.6667
>> x2(f)
error: x2(6.66667): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^63)-1 or logicals
```

You don't get the error in the actual loop, because the `1:ts` iteration actually creates integers in the range:

```
>> 1:ts
ans =

   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

In `numpy`:

```
In [1]: ts = 6.6667
In [3]: np.arange(0,ts)
Out[3]: array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

While `arange` steps by 1s, the actual values are float, hence the indexing error.

And a variable, array, cannot be created by this assignment:

```
In [6]: x2[0]=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [6] in <cell line: 1>
    x2[0]=1
NameError: name 'x2' is not defined
```

Correct ways of creating such an array/list in Python:

```
In [14]: x2 = np.zeros(6)
    ...: for i in range(6):
    ...:     x2[i] = i**2
    ...: 
In [15]: x2
Out[15]: array([ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 16., 25.])
In [16]: alist = []
    ...: for i in range(6):
    ...:     alist.append(i**2)
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [17]: alist
Out[17]: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

But your `f` loop just puts the same value in all slots

```
for f = 1:ts
    x2(f) = x1(end);
end
```

for that we really should use whole-array methods:

```
In [21]: x2 = np.full(6,fill_value=2.3)
In [22]: x2
Out[22]: array([2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3])
```

or:

```
In [25]: x2=np.zeros(6)
    ...: x2[:] = 2.3
```

In MATLAB you can get away with lots of iterations, since it does `jit` compilations.  But `numpy` is like the original MATLAB, where compiled whole-array methods are much faster.